# Running Groovy Unit Tests from a Eclipse Plugin Fragment?

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, rcp

i'm currently working on a Eclipse RCP Project. I have a Plugin Fragment where i store my Unit Tests. I like to store the Groovy Unit Tests there as well. But when i try to create a Groovy unit test, Eclipse doesn't let me, because the fragment is not a Groovy Project. Is there a way to run the the groovy tests inside the fragment? Or should i stop trying?

Thanks!

Patrick

Comment: Why not turn your project into a Groovy Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to turn your project into a groovy project, then you can create a text file with a .groovy extension and open it in a groovy editor.  However, you will not get many nice editor features.  Content assist, navigation, the outline view, etc will be inactive.

I would recommend that you convert the project into a groovy project, and create a source folder where all of your groovy unit tests would go.  From there, you can run your tests, etc.  If you don't want your groovy tests being built from PDE, then you can simply exclude that souurce folder from your build.properties file.

Comment: Thanks, i think i first try the groovy project.